# Show tooltip on function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tooltip

I am wanting to show a tooltip only on a specific function.

Here is the function

```
    $('#search').submit(function (e) {
    //check atleat 1 checkbox is checked
        if (!$('.its').is(':checked')) {
            //prevent the default form submit if it is not checked
            $( ".pk" ).tooltip({
                content: "Please select a source"
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        }
   })
```

I want to make a tooltip appear only if they do not have a checkbox selected and they have tried to submit the form, the tooltip will prompt them to check a box before submitting the form.

Is this possible with the jQuery Tooltip widget? All I am finding about the Tooltip widget is how to use `onHover` or `onClick` If not is there a recommended tooltip script to use for something like this, or is there a way for me to go about this differently?

Comment: Is this part of your code working? If so, you just need to add the code to display your message (be it tooltip or injecting some markup or whatever) inside your condition, no?

Comment: @BrianFitzGerald yes this part is working but when I try to add the tooltip code it doesn't show anything

Comment: add what you have tried in the question.

Comment: @guradio I added the tooltip function that I have been trying to use.

Comment: For what it's worth, you could probably do something simpler than including a beefy jquery tooltip plugin into your project if it's just for this use case. Maybe just inject a `span` tag with and error message and position it above the input box. If you insist on using the plugin, you should test it in isolation and just get it working on its own first, then plugging it into this context should be no problem. If you can't get it to work, you could try another tooltip plugin, or setup a jsfiddle so we can play with it, or take the simpler approach I mentioned above (injecting the span).